# Loading application.properties file in a non SpringBoot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've a set of microservices built with spring boot and using feign as client. All is working perfectly, but I have a problem with a non SpringBoot application.

In this case I would like to use configuration properties file (application.properties) to configure different client (like Ribbon). 
In my configuration bean I've included @ImportAutoConfiguration for all the components, but configuration is not loaded from properties file.

Is there a way to perform this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
@RequestMapping("/url")
@Controller
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class StudentController{
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  //get properties using keys
  //env.getProperty("key");

}
```

and put config.properties file inside `src/main/resources`